# How to measure where your site/app ranks in Anderson's UX pyramid?

Tags: ux-field, research, measuring

How could one measure how your website or app scores on Anderson's UX pyramid?

My goal would be to get a clear view of the current status per site/app upon how well are we doing and what could be improved on.

Maybe some kind of scoring mechanism that would rate different points within each block of the pyramid?

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Thanks in advance[image: User Experience Hierarchy of Needs model]

Following is a PDF link that explains the pyramid in detail (on pages 11, 12, and 13):
https://www.starzer.net/is1/docs/seductive-ixd-chapter-1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The Anderson's UX Pyramid is a hypothetical framework, which does not provide any measures or metrics for assessment. There are several [standardized questionnaires](https://measuringu.com/three-branches-ux/) such as UMUX (Usability Metric for User Experience) or UEQ (User Experience Questionnaire), as well as well-known SUS (System Usability Scale).

SUS would not be helpful to provide different scores for different aspects of the evaluated system, but [it can be benchmarked with other sites](https://measuringu.com/sus/).

UMUX is a shorter and more recent equivalent of SUS, which also provides score on usability. Here is a link to the [full text article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220054775_The_Usability_Metric_for_User_Experience).

[UEQ](https://www.ueq-online.org/) would give you a set of scores to understand the Hedonic Quality and Pragmatic Quality of your site or app (or any other artefact that can is used for doing something, like a tool), which may be more close to Anderson's levels.

Answer (score 0):

It would be quite difficult to get the same level of granularity as the Anderson's UX pyramid, but the way that the different levels of user experience is ranked gives us a clue as to how we can possibly go about it as a starting point.

I suggest that the 'chasm' that is difficult to cross, which is at the level of CONVENIENT allows you to at least work out which side your organisation's products and services lie. And if you look immediately below CONVENIENT there is USABLE, which is a relatively well-defined quality that can be measured semi-quantitatively in many different ways (look for questions relating to measuring usability or usability testing).

There are more formal processes to dissect the various levels of experiences, again not at the granularity that the pyramid describes, but a starting point would be the Kano's model of customer satisfaction that defines 'Delighters' which can help you see if there are elements of your products/services that lie in the DESIRABLE level.

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting problem to solve although there are small chances to get it right fast. If you are open to a series of experiments then it's doable.
Many things depend on what are **your resources and access** to the end-users - and also are they collaborating?

1. If YES -> then the straightforward would be adding the **questionnaire** which asks the user to rate the parameters you named from 1 to 10 (min time to get it done also). Here the articulation of your ask would be very important and will have an impact on what category of users will react to your ask. I would possibly add a textarea to get freeform feedback.
   1b) straightforward isn't always the best approach - also reply's tend to change once they are asked specific questions. Variations of questions would be important - "How likely you are to recommend our website?" might be a better indicator than "*Please rate how convenient our website is from 1 to 10*". But you will have a hard time separating this answer from "*how much do you enjoy our service?*"
2. if NO (say you are not allowed to place anything on this website)-> then I don't see anything rather than interviewing, can be online - not too hard. Here you may have a procedure to help evaluate the metrics you look for by an interviewer. Say, if a person has a quick answer to the question "*what do you like here?*" that's a good indication of the website being useful and pleasing to use. Here you need some *baseline questions to differentiate* quick thinkers from people who take their time as well as some time to switch a person from their own mood into some neutral state to eliminate mood effects. The decision on a number of your respondents is tied to your timeframe, budget, and so on.
   Wish you good luck with this project!

Answer (score 0):

First, there are ways to produce a measure or device that attempts to accomplish your task. The exercise, in my experience in similar academic exercises would depend on creating a foundation to work from. To start, accurate results depend on your ability to create a shared definition of the 6 experiences. Next would be too validate the quality of each shared definition for consistency.

If you could achieve a consistent validation index then you may be ready to create an instrument. There are confounding factors:

Language would be an issues and you may have to validate for each spoken language.

There would be a trade-off between a high correlation of experiences and population for whome the instrument would be effective.

There are others as well